# Select subscription date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to turn a date into last month's date?

```
SELECT extract(day from (Select (period_start) from accounts where id = 'id')) AS "Day of month";
```

The above give me the day of the month

**Account Table**

- id (primary)
- startPeriod

**User records**

- timestamp
- account_id (foreign key)

The user is registered at `02-12`for subscription start

I would like to have a query to select the date range from the current month to last month

This current month is April, so I would like to select the record that is

`select records from table where date > '03-12-2022'`

1. get the subscription start period and get the date
2. set the query limited to last month with the subscription start date

how to produce this date `03-12-2022` which is driven by subscription start period and previous month?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work:

1. Get the number of months between the subscription date and today e.g. age(timestamp1, timestamp2)
2. Get the number of months and subtract 1 to get last month e.g. duration = extract(month from age(timestamp1, timestamp2)) - 1
3. Add the months to the subscription date e.g. (subscription_date + (duration || ' month')::INTERVAL)

Comment: thanks, i couldn't find a set day function in Postgres. I think all i need is set day -1 month and set the day (3th/4th)